# .Net MVC - Accessing Custom Identity User Properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have added some custom fields to IdentityUser in the IdentityModel (such as First Name) however I am having trouble accessing those fields in the view. They have been added to the database through migrations and I have put information in them.

This is my model -

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}`
```

In the view I created a table to view this information

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th class="c">
        First Name
    </th>
    <th class="c">
        Surname
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="c">
            @item.FirstName
        </td>
        <td class="c">
            @item.Surname
        </td>   
    </tr>
}
```

I have called the model at the top of the view page

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
```

However this is where I am getting errors. For the @item. it does not recognise my custom fields. The specific error im getting is -

'IdentityUser' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityUser' could be found.

Im not sure why this error is showing up and I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the model to your custom class:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: Your answer did not work however I added the Models before the Application User -     @model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.Models.ApplicationUser>    and now it works successfully

Comment: I am glad to hear that. That was my intent to specify the namespace of the ApplicationUser class. So please accept this answer

Comment: Also I have another quick question. I have another custom field in that model called PhotoUpload which saves uploaded images as byte (through controller). How would I be able to call that PhotoUpload to view the image and not the byte characters? Thanks

Comment: You should convert the PhotoUpload property to URL and add a controller that would return the image when that URL hit. You may publish it as a separate question, if you need a detailed answer.

Comment: Yes I may publish as another question. Thanks for previous answer though